# Test-Automation using Selenium (Nemo.js) using Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have two excel sheets.  One is "Filters" and another is "Log". I need to call LogValidation() next to transaction.addSuccess().

How to combine both these functions and automate my code, and write in one data_driven().

I should able to validate - 1st row from 1st sheet next 1st row from 2nd sheet and so on.

Below is my code.

```
excel2json.parseAllSheets("test/functional/testData/ExcelFile.xlsx",function(result){
    multipleXlsxData = result;
    console.log(multipleXlsxData);
});

data_driven(multipleXlsxData.Filters, function() {
    it('External Type G Filters validation', function (trans, done) {  
        transaction.addSuccess( trans.date_range, trans.from_date, trans.transaction_status, trans.transaction_amount).then(util.doneSuccess(done));  
    });
});

data_driven(multipleXlsxData.Log, function() {
    it('External Type G Log validation', function (trans, done) {
        transaction.LogValidation(trans.date, trans.Status, trans.Gross_Amount, trans.Net_Amount, trans.Running_Balance, trans.Amount).then(util.doneSuccess(done));  
    });
});
```

Thanks in Advance